# Additional functionality Events provide over delegate

Tags: c#, events

As I understand an Event is a way for a class to allow clients to give it delegates to methods that should be called when the event occurs. When the event occurs, the delegate(s) given to it by its clients are invoked.

But as demonstrated in following code above said functionality can also be achieved by delegate only i.e. without using delegate.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListWithChangedEvent lwce = new ListWithChangedEvent();
        lwce.delegateVariable = DelegateTestMethod;
        lwce.Add("test");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DelegateTestMethod(object sender, object e)
    {

    }
}

public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, object e);

public class ListWithChangedEvent : System.Collections.ArrayList
{
    public override int Add(object value)
    {
        int result = base.Add(value);
        if (delegateVariable != null)
            delegateVariable(this, "");
        return result;
    }

    public ChangedEventHandler delegateVariable;

}
```

So, I was wondering what additional functionality does Events provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, I was wondering what additional functionality does Events provide?

Events provide two distinctly different advantages over exposing a public delegate:

1. You're making the intent very clear.  A delegate is typically exposed publically for a very different purpose than an "event" - by using an event, you're very clearly saying "this is something that will get raised at a specific point".  Exposing a delegate typically has a different meaning - most often a delegate in a public API is a *required* input for that API - ie: something that is used directly by the method, not an optional notification mechanism triggered by the method.
2. Events, technically, are not *necessarily* just a delegate.  An event actually has the option of allowing custom [add and remove accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx), which allow you to manually determine what happens when a subscriber subscribes or unsubscribes from the event.  For example, many implementations of [ICommand.CanExecuteChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx) actually don't include their own delegate at all - but [silently route to the CommandManager's RequerySuggested](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/) event.

Answer (score 0):

Your example allows for a single delegate to be called.  The `event` is a collection of delegates, meaning you can `+=` and `-=` your heart away (even during event invocation).

Comment: You can `+=` and `-=` normal delegate too.

Comment: @svick but you can't `=` to event !

Comment: @RoyiNamir, how is that related to what this answer says?

Comment: @svick  it was in reply your comment. just for clarify.

Answer (score 0):

event is just the  `access approach` to the handler.

it wont allow you to do `myHandler=myFunc;`
only using `+=` ( from outer class)

it was made that if another dumb use your code - so he wont destroy your chain by using `=` so you allow him only `+=` or `-=`

Comment: Event is not an access modifier. And you're completely ignoring the fact that you can have custom event accessors.

Comment: @svick read that before you answer .  http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2005/08/31/the-c-event-keyword-is-an-access-modifier-for-delegate-members/

Comment: if im from another class and try to cancel the chain by `=` so it wont let me ( event) - but if its a handler it will . its just protect the chain of function of the handler.

Comment: I think the C# specification is a more authoritative in this matter. And it clearly defines what access modifiers are (§10.3.5) and it doesn't list `event` among them. And it doesn't make sense to call it that. Event is not just a field with different accessibility, it's something else.

Comment: My answer is as with Moo-Juice's answer ( p.s. ive corrected the keyword term - which was incorrect.)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - wat do u exactly mean by another dumb?